# Can't use Swift in WatchKit extension

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

I have an iOS app that has a WatchKit App and WatchKit Extension written for watchOS 2.x, mainly in Objective-C. Any project files that are included in the WatchKit Extension target refuse to recognize any Swift code. An error is thrown at the line importing the generated interface:

```
#import "[ModuleName]-Swift.h"
```

It says file not found.

Is there something preventing use of Swift in watchOS 2 and earlier, or is there something wrong with my build settings?

Comment: Have you use bridging between Obj-C and Swift??

Comment: Having the same problem. Any resolution?